# Extract zip archive with Python zipfile.Zipfile, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to extract a .zip file with following python script but I am  getting the following error.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code is as follows:

```
>>> import zipfile
>>> import os
>>> source_dir = "c:\\TEST"
>>> dest_dir = "c:\\TEST"
>>> for src_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.zip')):
...     base = os.path.basename(src_name)
...     dest_name = os.path.join(dest_dir, base[:-4])
...     with zipfile.Zipfile((src_name, 'r') as infile:
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    with zipfile.Zipfile((src_name, 'r') as infile:
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Mismatched parentheses. `zipfile.Zipfile(src_name, 'r')`

Comment: you're having an extra bracket that's not needed

Comment: You have an extra left parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

you have mismatch with the parentheses

Comment: if I correct the parentheses, i get following error:

Comment: 8     base = os.path.basename(src_name)
      9     dest_name = os.path.join(dest_dir, base[:-4])
---> 10     with zipfile.Zipfile(src_name,'r') as infile:
     11         infile.extractall(dest_dir)
     12 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Zipfile'

Comment: Wrong capitalization. It's `ZipFile` (capital F). In the future... `dir(zipfile)`

Comment: Thanks ssnobody,, That was it! ZipFile. appreciate it.